# Vertically center in div differs on mobile vs desktop?

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, centering

I've been trying to center a number inside of a circle, and I just can't quite get it. Every time I think I have it, it seems like it on some platform it doesn't work (whether it's an apple phone, an android browser, Safari on Mac OS X, or Chrome / Firefox on Windows) there's a 1-2 pixel difference.

Here's the code:

```css
.unread-replies {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #F24648;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 1px solid #00000066;
}

* {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji" !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="unread-replies">1</div>
```

Fiddle copy here: https://jsfiddle.net/3vr2mkfb/3/

In this case it seems like it's not vertically centered on Chrome in my desktop browser, but it *is* vertically centered on Chrome on my Android phone. Why the discrepancy?

If I try small hacks like `padding-bottom: 2px;` then it inevitably causes some problem on some other platform. I think I instead need the actual fix, but I don't know if there is one?

Comment: Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add some line-height with the same value as the font-size and see if it fixe anything.

Comment: I tried this and it _almost_ fixes it. It's now perfectly centered on desktop but 1-2 pixels off on mobile

Comment: This answer is close enough. I'm fine with it being 1 pixel off center, as previously it was 2 pixels off.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Viewport Units** like **vw** for **width** and **vh** for **height** instead of **px** and **%** because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive.

It will surely solve your issue but if it doesn't let me know in the coments I will try my best to help you.